# Future simple or present simple?

Tags: present-tense, conditional-future

Which one is the correct sentence?

- If you need a dictionary, **I'll lend** you mine.
- If you need a dictionary, **I lend** you mine.

Comment: "I lend" would be ungrammatical. However, it will work in speech because it sounds the same as "I'll lend." Ha!

Comment: "I lend" is perfectly grammatical, but it is used in different circumstances. With "I lend" this is timeless or habitual. It could follow something like "Every week we go to French class, but we share our books". In the context the OP probably means, it has to be "I'll lend".

Comment: Hi Ana, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are grammatically correct because they are of different types.
The first one is 'First Conditional'. It refers to real future situations. The verb form in the main clause is usually in the so called 'Future Simple Tense' /will and the bare Infinitive/ or there is a modal complex predicate /must, may, etc. and bare Infinitive/.
 The second one is 'Zero Conditional'. It refers to permanent situations which are always true. The verb form in the main clause is in one of the Present Tenses /nearly always the Present Simple/.

Comment: In fact, however, the two sentences would not be distinguishable in normal speech; _I'll lend you mine_ sounds just like _I lend you mine_ because of the contraction. So there is only a difference in writing, and that's not likely for a sentence like this one.

Comment: I agree. Thee are no geminates in contemporary English pronunciation.

Comment: (Well, except for incidental ones like _bookcase_ and _hat-tip_.)

Comment: Yes. I meant only linking words in speech, not compounds.